# split php array by value

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
array
  0 => 
    array

      'prodid' => string '2' (length=1)
      'qty' => int 2
      'price' => string '100.00' (length=6)
      'sid' => string '13' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array

      'prodid' => string '3' (length=1)
      'qty' => int 1
      'price' => string '380.00' (length=6)
      'sid' => string '13' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array

      'prodid' => string '8' (length=1)
      'qty' => int 1
      'price' => string '300.00' (length=6)
      'sid' => string '24' (length=2)
```

How can i split it in to a multi dimentional array where the values 'sid' match like so.

```
array
  0 => 
    array

      0 => 
        array
          'prodid' => string '2' (length=1)
          'qty' => int 2
          'price' => string '100.00' (length=6)
          'sid' => string '13' (length=2)
      1 => 
        array
          'prodid' => string '2' (length=1)
          'qty' => int 2
          'price' => string '100.00' (length=6)
          'sid' => string '13' (length=2)

  1 => 
    array

      0 => 
        array
          'prodid' => string '7' (length=1)
          'qty' => int 1
          'price' => string '200.00' (length=6)
          'sid' => string '15' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// $ouput array will be indexed by the 'sid' value
$output = array();

// Iterate over the main array and create a new subarray if 
// it doesn't already exist, or add to it if it does.
foreach($input as $subarr) {
  if (!isset($output[$subarr['sid']]) {
    // New array indexed by sid
    $output[$subarr['sid']] = array();
  }
  // Append the whole array
  $output[$subarr['sid']][] = $subarr;
}
```

Note: this produces slightly different output than you described, in that it uses the `sid` as array keys rather than just indexing them from 0:

```
array
  // Note key difference...
  // sid == 13
  13 => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'prodid' => string '2' (length=1)
          'qty' => int 2
          'price' => string '100.00' (length=6)
          'sid' => string '13' (length=2)
      1 => 
        array
          'prodid' => string '2' (length=1)
          'qty' => int 2
          'price' => string '100.00' (length=6)
          'sid' => string '13' (length=2)
  // sid == 15
  15 => 
    array

      0 => 
        array
          'prodid' => string '7' (length=1)
          'qty' => int 1
          'price' => string '200.00' (length=6)
          'sid' => string '15' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You pick the value you want to group with as key for a new array and push the member to it

```
$new = array();
foreach($array as $member)
{
    $key = $member['group-value'];
    $new[$key][] = $member;
}
```

You then extract the bare values from the new array by using `array_values`:

```
$new = array_values($new);
```

And that's it. If you want to spare the last part, you can also create the mapping of keys and it's numerical index on your own:

```
$new = array();
$keys = array();
foreach($array as $member)
{
    $key = $member['group-value'];
    isset($keys[$key]) || $keys[$key] = count($keys);        
    $new[$keys[$key]][] = $member;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For PHP5.3+

```
$result = array_reduce (
  $array,
  function ($item, $result) {
    if (!isset($result[$item['sid']])) $result[$item['sid']] = array();
    $result[$item['sid']][] = $item;
    return $result;
  },
  array()
)
```