# Php split multidimensional array by value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Good Night, i need some help with my PHP code.
I have 1 big array that cointains read data from some machines.
The machines ID is the row "idSensor".

I want to split this big into another arrays grouped by the row idSensor.

**What i have at the moment**

```
 Array
(
    [1010_0] => Array
        (
            [ï»¿IdSensorData] => 1
            [Timestamp] => 2015-06-16 18:08:23.000
            [idSensor] => 1010
            [IdEnergyPrice] => 1
            [ReadData] => 1459
            [ReadEnergyPrice] => 0
        )

[1010_1] => Array
    (
        [ï»¿IdSensorData] => 73
        [Timestamp] => 2015-06-16 18:09:22.000
        [idSensor] => 1010
        [IdEnergyPrice] => 1
        [ReadData] => 1477
        [ReadEnergyPrice] => 0
    )

[1011_0] => Array
    (
        [ï»¿IdSensorData] => 2
        [Timestamp] => 2015-06-16 18:08:23.000
        [idSensor] => 1011
        [IdEnergyPrice] => 1
        [ReadData] => 1183
        [ReadEnergyPrice] => 0
    )

[1011_1] => Array
    (
        [ï»¿IdSensorData] => 74
        [Timestamp] => 2015-06-16 18:09:23.000
        [idSensor] => 1011
        [IdEnergyPrice] => 1
        [ReadData] => 1307
        [ReadEnergyPrice] => 0
    )

)
```

**What i want to achieve**

```
Array 1010
         [Timestamp] => 2015-06-16 18:08:23.000,[ReadData] => 1459
         [Timestamp] => 2015-06-16 18:09:22.000,[ReadData] => 1477

Array 1011
         [Timestamp] => 2015-06-16 18:08:23.000,[ReadData] => 1183
         [Timestamp] => 2015-06-16 18:09:23.000,[ReadData] => 1307
```

Here is my main function csv.php

```
function getarray($ip,$readinterval)
{
        global $db; /*variavel global pois a funcao nao a consegue ir buscar diretamnte aos includes*/
        $sensores = array();/*Array para armazenar os sensores*/
        $resultado = array();/*Array para armazenar os resltados da pesquisa do csv*/
        /*Vamos buscar a base de dados os idSensor com o IP e intervalo de leitura que desejamos*/
        $sql = "SELECT idSensor FROM Sensor where IP = '{$ip}' and ReadInterval = '{$readinterval}'" or die("Erro na query");
        $result = $db->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
                echo "Temos resultados para o edificio: " .$ip." e tempo de leitura: ".$readinterval. " min</br></br>";
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                 {
                         $sensores[] = $row["idSensor"];
                 }

        } else {
                        echo "Nao encontrou resultados";
                }
        $db->close();
        /*Agora para cada sensor  do vetor sensores vamos buscar as suas informacoes ao CSV e armazenar tudo dentro do resultado*/
        foreach ($sensores as $value)
        {
                $csv = new parseCSV();
                $csv->conditions = "idSensor is '{$value}'";
                $csv->sort_by = 'idSensor';
                $csv->auto('eco.csv');
                $csv->parse('eco.csv');
                $resultado = array_merge($resultado,$csv->data);
        }
        /*Apresenta os resultados todos formatados*/
        print "<pre>";
        print_r($resultado);
        print "</pre>";
```

Comment: Can you provide the JSON encoded version of the source array?

Comment: foreach loop would be a good start

Comment: Can you show us what you did to get such a messy table of Arrays?.

Comment: Thanks for the help , i have edited the question and added the php function. I am using the csv library parsecsv.lib.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you can collect your data structure in your main loop.

I haven't tested the code, so I'm not sure. May be it will get you somewhere close.

```
   foreach ($sensores as $value)
    {
            $csv = new parseCSV();
            $csv->conditions = "idSensor is '{$value}'";
            $csv->sort_by = 'idSensor';
            $csv->auto('eco.csv');
            $csv->parse('eco.csv');

            $resultArray[$csv->data['idSensor']][] = array ('Timestamp' => $csv->data['Timestamp'], 'ReadData' => $csv->data['ReadData']);

            $resultado = array_merge($resultado,$csv->data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $newArr = [ ];
       foreach($your_data as $key => $val) {
                     if($key == 'idSensor') {
                         $newArr[$key][ ] = ['Timestamp' => $val['Timestamp'], 'ReadData => $val['ReadData']
                      }
        }
        print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score -1):

After searching a little bit more I found what I was looking for.

[SPlit PHP array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402031/split-php-array-by-value)

I made some modifications on the code and I solved my problem.
Thanks all.